# WIF in MVC.net - Adding Additional Claims to SAML Token from Second IP

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wif, saml

I've got an MVC.net application that uses an MVC.net identity provider (IP-1) for it's authentication. After a user has logged on, I need to get some additional claims from another application (IP-2). I'm doing this by passing the token back to IP-2, which is able to read the token and add additional claims before generating a new token.

The problem comes when I try to pass the new token to the RP, as the client is already authenticated with the RP, and so the new token and it's claims are ignored.

I think what I'm trying to do is explained below, but I'm also aware that my knowledge of WIF is a bit shaky, so there may be some flaws in my assumptions of how things should work.

My question is, how do I get the RP to re-authenticate using the new token? Also, is there a better way to add the claims without having to recreate the token in the IP-2 application?

[image: Sequence Diagram]

Comment: Are all claims available to all authenticated users?

Comment: No, most of the time users of the RP won't use any claims from IP-2.

Answer (score 2):

To accept a new SAML token you need to clear the session Cookie and then send a new signin request. But......

Sending the SAML Token from IP-1 to the other (IP-2) goes fundamentally against the SAML and WS-Fed designs. The SAML token is meant for the RP. It is not supposed to be sent to anyone else!! If the SAML Token is encrypted for the RP, then IP-2 cannot even read it. And there is (of course) no standard way to add the first token info to the second authentication request.

Cascading (one first, then the other adds claims) is the standard solution. In your case it sounds like redirect through IP-2 to IP-1. IP-1 sets its normal claims. IP-2 adds its claims and then does the final return to the RP.

Comment: The SAML token isn't exactly sent to the IP-2. IP-2 is also a RP of IP-1 and will do it's own request for a token. Essentially it's the same token, but it's issued to the IP-2 separately. I believe the outcome is the same though, so I'm open to better ways to do that.


Do you have any links to the best way to achieve cascading? What you describe in your last paragraph is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: OK then your setup isn't as unsafe as I had feared :-) {I had to remain polite} You are almost there. Just kill the SessionToken of IP-1. Then redirect to IP2. That is perfect. But you will need to trust two identity providers in your WIF web.config (several add elements  in "issuerNameRegistry") and you will need to do one redirect to an IdP "manually" (i.e. not automatically), because WSFAM only has one IdP configuration for automatic redirect.